# Kernel driver read memory is not sending the whole string

Tags: c++, c, kernel, kmdf

I have this kernel driver used to read a string from the process memory:

```
KeAttachProcess(GlobalProcessPE);
char* source = *(ULONG*)pBuf;

RtlZeroMemory(pBuf, pIoStackLocation->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength);
RtlCopyMemory(pBuf, source, 256);

KeDetachProcess();
```

And here is the communication process in C++:

```
DWORD ReadBuffer2[180] = { 0 };
DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_READPROCMEM_S, &msg, sizeof(msg), ReadBuffer2, sizeof(ReadBuffer2), &dwBytesRead, NULL);
printf("Message: %s\n", ReadBuffer2);
printf("Bytes read: %d\n", dwBytesRead);
```

Upon running and searching for the string, it actually captures the first four letters from it, as well as displaying the following:

```
Message: ABCD
Bytes read: 4
```

I have checked the string using an alternative method, and it is supposed to display ABCDEFGHIJKL...

The question lies here, why is it only reading (or probably writing) the first four bytes alone?

Comment: `char* source = *(ULONG*)pBuf;` wtf?

Comment: pBuf is the Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer, which is supposed to be the address of the memory I am reading.

Comment: That was not my point!

Comment: Please state your point as I do not understand whether it is wrong to obtain the char pointer from an unsigned long...?

Comment: This assumes that a `ULONG` is equivalent to a pointer, and not a safe bet. `SystemBuffer` is already a pointer, so there is no need to do this.

Comment: You are assigning an integer to a pointer. Good luck running that on Win64.

Comment: Are you assuming that there will be an address stored at `SystemBuffer` that you are trying to recover?

Comment: Thank you Hans, I will fix those shortly and get back to you.

Comment: The reason it is 254 is because I am expecting a certain string for the moment (for testing purposes) - nevertheless, it still hasn't affected the code. Using ULONG_PTR instead of ULONG will cause an illegal indirection, thus forcing me to use * (ULONG *) knowing that pBuf is PVOID. - The method provided above is similar to the method Cheat Engine uses, if not, the same.

Comment: I did change the InputBufferLength with the OutputBufferLength yet it hasn't affected the code in any way.  Also, I do not see a point in providing a negative vote to the question...?

Comment: @HansPassant: On what basis do you think that "`sizeof(ReadBuffer2)` is 4 times too small"?  `DeviceIoControl` size arguments are measured in bytes, same as `sizeof`.

Comment: seriously, what's wrong with ` *(char **)`

Comment: @user3528438 changing *(ULONG *) with *(char **) caused a BSOD.

Comment: if that's the case, then your code has more things wrong than you think

Comment: The code is based off Cheat Engine's driver, it's the best way to read the memory according to some.

Comment: its suppose to be `*(char *)` not `*(char **)` that will stop the BSOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to read the string by reading each 4 characters at every address + 4.

Here's the communication code: (I also added some a __try {} _except () {} in the Driver so it doesn't BSOD)

```
std::string str = "";
bool scanning = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    if (!scanning) break;

    msg = 0x095A2A28 + i * 0x4;
    DWORD ReadBuffer2[50] = {0};
    DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_READPROCMEM_S, &msg, sizeof(msg), ReadBuffer2, sizeof(ReadBuffer2), &dwBytesRead, NULL);
    char dtostr[4];
    sprintf(dtostr, "%s", ReadBuffer2);
    for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
        str += dtostr[l];
        if (dtostr[l] == '\0') {
            scanning = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
std::cout << "~Message: " << str << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to "kernel land". This answer may be a bit late, but better than never right ?

What you are doing to send/read the data is not safe and ugly.

To send the whole string to user mode, here is an example:

```
PCHAR data = "This String is from Device Driver !!!";
size_t datalen = strlen(data) + 1;//Length of data including null

RtlCopyBytes(Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer, data, irpStack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength);
```

This assumes that you are not using UNICODE, and note that although this example is working 100%, it's not complete and needs to be improved.

Enjoy.